# PHP Startup Unable to load dynamic library /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll

Tags: php, mysqli, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-14.04

I have ubuntu 14.04 EC2 instance. I have installed php 7 on it. when I execute any php command like php --version or any other. I get following error

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

I have tried following

1. enable php_mysqli.dll in php.ini
2. enable mysqli.so
3. enable php_mysqli.so
4. sudo apt-get install php-mysql

but nothing worked for me.

Any suggestion how I can solve this?

Answer (score 18):

If you are on Linux, you shouldn't have DLL files but SO files. 
So first, you have to remove / disable the php_mysqli.dll you added in php.ini.

In order to use mysqli, you should then :

- install the package for Ubuntu : `apt-get install php-mysql`
- check if it is already enabled (with `phpinfo()` for example)
- if not enabled, enable the module - check in `/etc/php/mods-available/` folder if there is a `mysqli.ini`, containing `extension=mysqli.so`, then check for CLI / FPM / Apache / other if there is the symbolic link pointing to this file (for example for CLI, in `/etc/php/cli/conf.d/` : `20-mysqli.ini -> ../../mods-available/mysqli.ini`)
- restart php / apache / nginx depending what you are using

Comment: I have checked and these all things are already done but still it is not working.

Comment: I have wsl2 with debian and - my fault - uncommented the php_mysqli.dll line. After commenting it again the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 14):

In my case, it happened because I uncommented the `extension=php_mysqli.dll` line in php.ini file for running some other package. After Googling around I found that you should not uncomment anything directly from php.ini instead you should install the required PHP extension and it will do the rest.

Answer (score 4):

If you are on Linux and using php8.1,

- try to commenting extension=pdo_mysql in directory /etc/php/8.1/cli/php.ini file if the extension is uncommenting
- uncommenting extension=pdo_mysql in directory
  /etc/php/8.1/apache2/php.ini file if the extension is commenting

this method work for me

Answer (score 2):

I have recently encountered this problem on ubuntu16.04, I finally resolve it by  adding a semi-colon at each line like `extension=php_*.dll`,I think that is because LAMP on ubuntu is intelligent enough，it automatically opens all of the extensions for us. And on windows,we have to enable the extensions manually by remove the semi-colon at each line like `;extension=php_*.dll` in `php.ini`.

Answer (score 2):

Run `Phpinfo()`
Search for your `php.ini` path

search `extension=php_mysqli.so`

comment like this

```
;extension=php_mysqli.so
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem and realised they were two folders in my `/etc/php/7.0`, which were `apache2` and `cli`. Turned out the extension line in `cli/php.ini` was uncommented with the dll file, not the one in `apache2` directory. Commenting it just solved the problem.

Comment: I had this problem with mysqli, openssl and curl, commented all of them as you indicated and perfect!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solved it like this:

1. add libs to php.ini (etc/php/7.3/apache2; etc/php/7.3/cli folders)
   extension=pdo_mysql.so
2. restart apache (sudo systemctl restart apache2)
3. comment libs in php.ini (etc/php/7.3/apache2; etc/php/7.3/cli folder)
   extension=pdo_mysql.so
4. go etc/php/7.3/mod_available
5. comment extension (because it is already loaded), for example, etc/php/7.3/mod_available/pdo_mysql.ini
   ;extension=pdo_mysql.so

Answer (score 0):

In my case, to resolve this issue, you should first check the version of php-mysqli in use. You can utilize php_info() to obtain this information. Once you are certain about what is causing the inability to load the dynamic library, navigate to one of the following files: php.ini in /etc/php/{your version of php}/cli/php.ini or /etc/php/{your version of php}/apache2/php.ini. In these files, comment out the lines 'extension=mysqli' (and in some cases, 'extension=mbstring' as well).

note: php7.4

Answer (score -1):

If you see mcrypt.so under /etc/php/7.2 or /etc/php/7.3 just delete it and restart the server it will resolve the issue.
As when we updrage the php to latest version that file may get stored to latest versions which is not required.

I used following commands:

> cd /etc/php/7.3
>
> sudo rm -rf mcrypt.so
>
> sudo service apache2 restart

Answer (score -2):

Just comment out all lines with .dll extensions because you are on Ubuntu. Ubuntu support .so files.

Answer (score -4):

In `php.ini` under `Dynamic Extensions` the line `extension=php_mysqli.dll` was enabled.

I disabled it by adding a semi-colon at the head of the line `;extension=php_mysqli.dll`.

Saved and exited `php.ini`. Restarted `Apache`.

This resolved the error for me.

Comment: Thats not the solution, you just remove the lib